# Take a picture without click with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have tried to take a picture from back and front camera and send it with email with Xamarin without user will need to click on any button like picture button.

I could not do that.

Is it possible to take a picture from back and front camera without any user click with Xamarin??

Comment: What does that have to do with sending an email? You do not have to tell us what you wanna do with that picture. Pretty sneeky it is though.

Comment: so you want to take pictures and send emails without the user knowing?  That sounds like a security nightmare

Comment: @Jason .no...user will accept this permission when he install the application.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend in how are you taking the picture. If you are using Xamarin.Essentials, then no, you can't.

You will need a little more control of the camera. Either a native implementation or a plugin.

You can use [CameraView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview) from Xamarin Community Toolkit. Check the example, you can trigger the ShutterCommand to get the picture.